# Joining 2 table using 1 JOIN and another LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I am currently using MySQL and I need to select from 3 tables. I have 3 table: Game, Game_genre and comments.

The Game table
[where GameID is the PK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz2Br.png)

The Game_genre table
[where GameID and GenreID is the PK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfLcF.png)

What I have tried is

```
SELECT G.GameTitle, G.Company, G.ReleaseDate, G.Description, G.Price, GG.GenreName, G.Preowned, G.ImagePath, round((G.Price*0.8),2)'SalesPrice'
from game G, game_genre GG, comments C
LEFT JOIN C ON G.GameID
LEFT JOIN GG on G.GameID
WHERE G.GameID = GG.GameID;
```

However, this comes out with a error of 1066 even though I have given each table an alias

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `JOIN` clauses you don't list all the tables in the `FROM` clause, only the first table goes there. And the relations between the tables go in the `ON` clause, not the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT G.GameTitle, G.Company, G.ReleaseDate, G.Description, G.Price, GG.GenreName, G.Preowned, G.ImagePath, round((G.Price*0.8),2)'SalesPrice'
FROM game G
LEFT JOIN C ON G.GameID = C.GameID
LEFT JOIN GG ON G.GameID = GG.GameID;
```

Please review your SQL textbook or tutorial to learn the basic syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax is:

```
SELECT G.GameTitle, G.Company, G.ReleaseDate, G.Description, G.Price,
       GG.GenreName, G.Preowned, G.ImagePath,
       round((G.Price*0.8),2) as SalesPrice
FROM game G LEFT JOIN
     comments C
     ON G.GameID = C.GameId LEFT JOIN
     game_genre GG 
     on G.GameId = GG.GameId;
```

I am guessing that the join on `Game_Genre` is on something like the `GenreId`; however, your code has it on `GameId`.

Also, don't use single quotes for column aliases.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Comment: The code is working but the results are missing the contents of the Comments table

Comment: @HuiZhen . . . Perhaps the `join` keys are not correct.  Without table layouts and sample data, we can only go on the information in the query in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just try like below:

`SELECT G.GameTitle, G.Company, G.ReleaseDate, G.Description, G.Price, GG.GenreName, G.Preowned, G.ImagePath, round((G.Price*0.8),2)'SalesPrice'
from game G 
LEFT JOIN game_genre GG ON G.GameID = GG.GameID
LEFT JOIN comments C ON G.GameID = C.GameID
WHERE <your condition>`

I would suggest you to learn a bit more about JOINS of SQL syntax :)

Comment: I have tried this but it only returns the data from Game and Game_genre not the comments table

Comment: Try Use "LEFT OUTER JOIN" instead, if possible show data screenshot of comments table

Comment: @Jagannath: it's exactly the same as LEFT JOIN. OUTER is a redundant keyword.

Comment: There are no records in Comments right now. The result should return NULL when selected